# Is it possible to create a references from text?

Tags: 7, nodes, entities

I'll explain problem with an example:

We have:

1. Text about apples
2. List of types of apples

Problem:

1. User inputs text about apples.
2. User selects text that describes certain type of apple, and then click 'magic button'
3. 'Magic button' creates a small window with input field for type of apple.
4. User enters type of apple, drupal creates that type of apple in list of types of apples.

Details:

1. Apples are described in text.
2. Types of apples will not be a plain text(fieds in content type called 'Apple Types')

Is this even feasible in drupal?

Can you point me in right direction of search? What kind of modules(combination of modules) would help me?

Answer (score 1):

It should be simple and straight forward as far as i understand. Below steps should solve the problem. You can solve it using Drupal Core itself and taxonomy module that comes with core.

- Create a Content Type called "About Apples".
- Add a text area field called "Apple Details".
- Create a Vocabulary called "Apple Types"
- Add a field called "apple type" , select field type as "term reference" and widget types as "Auto Complete term widget (Tagging)"

That's it ! You just created a content type called About apples which gives you a form to add Apple Details & Auto Complete Category widget which stores new terms to Apple Types vocabulary and shows autocomplete results when user tries to add categories.